# iOS App crashes when the service is closed

Tags: ios, swift, rest, mobile, swift4

I've been writing an app with Swift 4 and it communicates with a service via RESTful API.

I have found some helpful code examples and everything works well as the service is running.

However, I could not handle the situation that the service is closed. I have tried try/catch blocks but they did not work well. Please check the code below firstly. It's the part of the communication. Basically it sends an email address to the service and gets a response as an activation code.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // Some code
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            // Some code
            return
        }
        do {
            guard let activation_response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
                as? [String: Any] else {
                    // Some code
                    return
            }
            guard let activation_code = activation_response["activation_code"] as? String else {
                // Some code
                return
            }
            // Some code, here, if it works fine.

        } catch  {
            // Some code
            return
        }
    }.resume()
```

When the service is closed, simply it will throw an error such as TCP connection failed. How can I handle it?

The error I get is something like below:

`TheApp[4184:399699] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x604000166600]: 1:61 Err(61)
2018-01-02 20:35:04.930874+0300 TheApp[4184:399699] Task <5ED49B16-BFDC-45A5-85F5-095C4FC4D84D>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2018-01-02 20:35:04.934352+0300 TheApp[4184:399698] Task <5ED49B16-BFDC-45A5-85F5-095C4FC4D84D>.<1> finished with error - code: -1004`

It throws an exception and I can not catch it. I could not find how to do it. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you work on a physical phone or on symulator?

Comment: I work on simulator

Comment: Can you put `debugPrint(data, response, error)` before all guards? And then add this to your question

Comment: Those aren't exception messages. What exception message do you get?  Which line doesn't your app crash on?

Comment: why not simply use alamofire ? Just wondering

Comment: Did You correctly added `NSAppTransportSecurity`  key in info.plist ?